# How to debounce a function inside modelChange function using lodash debounce?

Tags: angular, lodash, angular-formly, debouncing

I have a function which invokes whenever the model changed. I want to use debounced function inside the modelChange function.

I am using `lodash` debounce but it is not invoking the function what am i doing wrong?

modelChange Function:

```
 onModelChange(model) {    
    _.debounce(function() {
      alert('debouned');
    }, 2000)
  }
```

Here is [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a5pvrq-tfghxm) to `Stackbiltz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating method for `debouncing` and calling it inside of `onModelChange` should do the trick:

```
debouncedOnChange = _.debounce(function() {
  alert('debounced');
}, 2000);

onModelChange(model) {
  // alert('model has been changed');
  this.debouncedOnChange();
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-debounce-a-function-inside-modelchange-function-using-lo?file=src/app/app.component.ts)